# Tracking WP Post Tags using Google Analytics and dataLayer (GTM)

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-layer

I set the dataLayer variable with the post author, tags and categories data. All these were already created as custom dimensions on Analytics.

The problem is that Post Tags and Categories are arrays, Do I have to split the arrays on Google Tag Manager? (Or something like that, IDK). I did a test with Post Categories setting up `pageCategory[0]` as Data Layer Variable Name (Because I need only the first category) but It's not working good.

The dataLayer looks like this:

```
{
"pagePostType":"post",
"pagePostType2":"single-post",
"pageCategory":["ha-kidd-knitting-supplies"],
"pageAttributes":["big-time-yarn","charles-voth","classic-shades","easy-knits","km066","knitted-cowl","textured-cowl","universal-yarn"],
"pagePostAuthor":"Charles Voth"
}
```

**What is the best way to collect all the wordpress post tags and categories as custom dimensions on Analytics?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dot notation to access the array, so your page cateogry dataLayer variable could have a value like:

```
pageCategory.0
```

For your page attributes, they could be accessed individually:

```
pageAttributes.1
pageAttributes.2
```

etc.

Of course with multiple page attributes, this wouldn't be the best way. You should instead define your dataLayer variable to have a value of just `pageAttributes`, and then you can loop through this variable to populate your Custom Dimensions, and then concatenate the strings.

Comment: I did it with the pageCategory value on the dataLayer and I'm gettin "not set" on Analytics (I configured not set as default value).

Comment: When are you trying to use those values? You would need to use them on page load (gtm.js).

Comment: I had configured the variables as Version 1, I already moved these to Version 2. What about if I use pageAttributes without dot notation? (Using Version 2 on GTW)... Each tag (array key) will be tracked separately on Analytics, right?

Comment: You must use dot notation to access dataLayer variable arrays (this doesn't really have anything to do with Version 1 or Version 2 - dataLayer always uses dot notation). Can you throw up some screenshots of how you are using these variables, including how your tag is triggered? Need to see if you are using this on the Page View event. Check also in your GTM debug window what the value of your variables are AT EACH EVENT. You should only see your correct dataLayer values on the page view.