# Tracking Wordpress Post Tags in Analytics using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to tracking some User data for each post tag. For this, I'm using Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager. The dataLayer looks like:

```
{
"pagePostType":"post",
"pagePostType2":"single-post",
"pageCategory":["ha-kidd-knitting-supplies"],
"pageAttributes":["big-time-yarn","charles-voth","classic-shades","easy-knits","km066","knitted-cowl","textured-cowl","universal-yarn"],
"pagePostAuthor":"Charles Voth"
}
```

The `pageAttributes` key contains the tags.

**How can I track all these tags without use dot notation?** The posts could have 1, 2, 3, 4... or more tags, so I can't use dot notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned here in this answer [Tracking WP Post Tags using Google Analytics and dataLayer (GTM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274378/tracking-wp-post-tags-using-google-analytics-and-datalayer-gtm) that for the `pageAttributes`, you should assign that as the value for a Data Layer type variable. That way you can just loop through that variable and access each element of that array.

[image]

Comment: Can you please specify how it's not working? On the "Page Load" event in GTM, what does the dataLayer variable have as its value?

Comment: this does not answer the question which is talking about GA and the answer is for GTM variable configuration (which does not affect tracking on GA).

Answer (score 0):

You could get the whole pageAttributes array using dataLayer variable in GTM and then get individual tags by using array length.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "array lenght"? On WP or GTM?

Comment: nyuen is correct, this was the approach I was taking about, and should work correctly. Please make sure than you are entering the name exactly same i.e pageAttributes